# Django - Sending Bulk Mails using django-mailer

Tags: django, django-mailer

I am using django-mailer for sending emails. I have cron job running to send mails from the queue every minute. I use GMail's SMTP server to send mails. django-mailer will send mails one by one. The issue is each e-mail is taking 3-5 seconds to be sent. Is there anyway to send these emails in parallel? My requirement is send at-least 150 mails per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to queue your outbound emails and then either use a number of SMTPs in a round-robin fashion, or single SMTP that allows parallel connections (I'm not sure if it's possible according to the relevant RFC).

Or you can install e.g. Postfix and make your Django app relay emails to it. Then it's a matter of Postfix configuration.

Comment: Yeah. I've used django-mailer + local smarthost for spiky / high volumes of mail and it's been fine. Though we were also using a dedicated STMP sending service (AuthSTMP) rather than shoving it all through a GMail/Google Apps Mail account, so postfix never really got backed up anyway.